# Let S = $\{(x, y, z) \;\text{which spans}\;\Bbb R^3\;|\; 2x = 3z \;,\;\; y = -z\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find any similar examples in my text book on this. I'm assuming that from this I can either have $x = 3/2z$ and $y = -z$ then have the set $\{3/2z, -z, z\}$ but I need to prove that this is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ . So I'm thinking of having $2x - 3z = 0$ and $y + z = 0$ but then what about my third vector? Any hints or suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it will span $\mathbb{R^3} $ because this subspace is of dimension 1 while $\mathbb{R^3} $ is of dimension 3.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading notation. The vectors should be v1 = x, v2 = y, v3 = z if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Then also all the vectors are linearly dependent so the subspace  is of dimension 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove that it is a subspace then you just need to check that it is a subset and then check that it meets the conditions to be a vector space - most of which is inherited. You wont get a set of linearly independent vectors, with fewer than three vectors in your set, to span $\mathbb{R}^3$. Some would take it as the definition of the dimension as the number of elements in the smallest linearly independent spanning set, hence if your set worked then the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3 = 1$!

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y,z)=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in S$ is not even element of $\mathbb R^3$, because it is a triple of vectors, so $S$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. But as Abhra Abir Kundu already mentioned there is no such triple that spans $\mathbb R^3$ and satisfies the given conditions.